# Are there additional (custom ?) tracks for Formula One?

Tags: custom-game-pieces, formula-one

Recently, I fell in love with the Formula One board game (not Formule D or Dé but [this game](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtq8rovv3ZAhWIPBQKHepZAgYQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFormula_1_(board_game)&usg=AOvVaw2vKFxhXjYWueC0sYyB0A_p)). It is very well balanced and doesn't really leave room for luck but rather relies on planning and resources/risk management.

Unfortunately, the version of the game I have only has one track which can get repetitive after a while. I have not been able to find other tracks even different versions of the game.

I would like to know if there is any known additional content (both official and custom).

I have already created some cars to replace the stock ones and I'm currently  trying to add known tracks such as Magny-Cours (currently 100x70cm board size). A second track would be helpful to have two references regarding the balancing of the new board.

---

*Side note 1 : I have tried to use Formule D tracks but they don't fit because the compartments are too big and need to be aligned. Also, the curves require speed limits.*

---

*Side note 2 : Sorry for the potential English mistakes. If the questions requires editing (question clarification or grammar-wise correction), feel free to point it out.*

Comment: You might be able to adapt the Championship Formula Racing games's courses (which do have speed limits for the corners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to BGG they have some print and play files.

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1535/formula-1/files

Also, Nice pick up!

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know about this website.
Sadly, there are only a few tracks for this game (it was to be expected). Hopefully, it'll help the creation of my new tracks.

Answer (score 3):

I’m a huge french fan of this extraordinary game.

You can find several interesting tracks on the Lucidphoenix site:
http://lucidphoenix.com/sc/tracks/

The owner of the site is Douglas Schultz, who remastered "Speed Circuit" in "CFR".

Comment: Douglas Shultz also explain how he build the tracks, very interesting :)

Comment: Oho, un français !
Thanks for the advice. I have now finished my track so I can also give some advice regarding track building as I think mine is pretty balanced.